# How can I get the smallest row

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I get the smallest row from my generated table I mean by generated table that I will generate a table by sub-query that counts the records then I will get the min row.

In other words, the problem that I'm trying to solve
I have a table: works_on which contains all the ssn for employees who work on project identified by pnumber
I want to determine the pnumber of the project that contain the min number of employees

Answer (score 1):

MAX ... KEEP

```
SELECT MAX( pnumber) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY cnt DESC)
FROM
  (SELECT pnumber, count(*) cnt
  FROM works_on
  GROUP BY pnumber)
```

If you have multiple projects with the same minimum, it gets a little complicated.

```
SELECT pnumber FROM works_on
GROUP BY pnumber
HAVING COUNT(*) =
  (SELECT MAX( cnt) max_cnt
  FROM
    (SELECT pnumber, count(*) cnt
    FROM works_on
    GROUP BY pnumber))
```

Comment: why you compare max count? the question is to find min value.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of other options for you to try.

You could try the simple approach, based on rownum

```
select *
from (
  SELECT pnumber, count(*) cnt
  FROM works_on
  GROUP BY pnumber
  order by cnt
)
where rownum < 2
```

Or use the `RANK` analytic function. The `DENSE_RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER` functions would work similarly (but each slightly differently.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT pnumber, cnt, rank() over (order by cnt) as my_rank
  from (
    SELECT pnumber, count(*) cnt
    FROM works_on
    GROUP BY pnumber
  )
)
WHERE my_rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (

select pnumber , count (pnumber)counter from works_on 

group by pnumber

)

where counter=(select min(counter) from (select pnumber , count (pnumber)counter from works_on 

group by pnumber

))
```